# Are quadratic forms always equal to their tranponse? $x^\top A x = x^\top A^\top x$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Is a quadratic form always equal to its transpose?
$$
x^\top A x \overset{?}{=} x^\top A^\top x.
$$
To me it seems like it should since the quadratic form is a scalar.

Comment: Totally correct .

Comment: furthermore, it is only the symmetric part of $A$  that contributes to the form value.

Comment: @Euler Yes. Indeed, the transpose of a scalar is itself. To clarify on Will's comment, the symmetric matrix $S = \frac 12 (A + A^\top)$ encodes the same quadratic form as $A$.